# Synchronize Sharepoint List with multiple Excel files

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have a list on Sharepoint,and I would like to update that list from any excel sheet/file I create "Having same formatting of course". Can I achieve that? I know that you can create a List on sharepoint from an excel sheet "Table Format" but I couldn't find any solution to sync sharepoint list from any excel sheet. Shall I do some scripting to achieve that ? I'm using Excel 2010 and Sharepoint 2010

Comment: you can use Excel VBA to call [SharePoint Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/930006) _might_ work for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I need further interaction with the list, I have decided to go with Access, which provides an out of the box solution. Simply create a blank database and link it with the desired list on SharePoint and that would be it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to actually do any further interactions with the SharePoint list?
If not, a solution could be to just display the excel sheeet as a Range within a page. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556820.aspx

Comment: Thank you, but yes I need to update that list frequently. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you get my point. Suggesting that you do not use a list at all. Just display the excel sheet directly.
If you do need to update a list from excel, you must use scripting of some kind. Question is if you can call the script from within excel, or it must happen when uploading the excel sheet.
Perhaps if you tell the complete scenario, it is easier to help.